# How can keep my mecurial repo on sourcetree without getting git status error

Tags: git, mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree

I have been having trouble with Sourcetree now for the past few days.

I have a mercurial repository with Bitbucket but have to move it a git repo although at the moment I still have to use the mercurial repository when I have to add new projects to it, but for some reason my source tree keeps giving me a git status failed with code 128: fatal: not a git repository. I know its not a git so I don't understand why it keeps giving me the error,which in the end keeps having me to re-install source tree and re-clone my repo so I can do my work.

Any help on the problem and how I can solve this issue would be great.

Comment: AFAIK there are still Mercurial hosting sites other than BitBucket, so you don't necessarily have to switch to git.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is still related to this [old 2017 issue](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-727), where you could, [as described here](http://blog.enazarov.ru/2015/04/source-tree-git-status-code-128.html):

> If  your SourceTree complains on startup saying that '`git status`' failed with code 128: `fatal: Not a git repository` (or any of the parent directories): `.git` (Here some folder) most likely the problem is that you have deleted a repository while tab with the repository was opened.
>
> To solve this navigate to
>
> "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\opentabs.xml",
>
> Open it with any text editor, and remove line pointing to the repository SourceTree complains about.
>   Save the file and restart SourceTree, the problem should disappear.

Even if you are not on Windows, you can look for those `bookmarks.xml` and `opentabs.xml`